# Arduino Nano - Multiple 5v Power Sources

Tags: arduino

I am planning on building a small device that sits inline for a SNES controller to allow remapping the buttons. My initial idea is to use an Arduino Nano, but I'm a bit unsure about how best to do it.

The console itsself has a 5v line going to the controller. My plan is to use this to power both the controller and the Nano. As far as I can tell, connecting this to the 5v line and backpowering it *should* be fine, but not ideal. I could also just connect it to the USB 5v port.

However, the plan is also to have input reading capabilities, which requires using USB to connect it to my PC.
I believe this may cause a bit of an issue, since the 5v from the SNES and the 5v from the USB connection could potentially conflict.

Is there any easy way round this?
What I really would need would be a diode on both the SNES 5v line and the USB 5v line, but I don't believe there's a way to do that.

Comment: Do you need to connect both 5V lines together? Just use one and don't connect the other to anything.

Comment: I want to connect the controller 5v direct to the board so it can work without the USB connected. I then want to be able to plug in the USB in should I want to connect it to the PC in addition to still being plugged into the console. 
From what I can tell, there's no easy way for me to disconnect the 5v into the board without opening the enclosure I'm planning on having it in and disconnecting the wire coming from the console.